# custom pages using asdoc

Tags: actionscript, documentation, asdoc

Does anyone know if you can write your own pages that asdoc will recognize and use? For instance, I'd like to write some "Getting Started","Support" and "FAQ" kind of pages that will help understanding what my actionscript classes are about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is apparently no way to write pages without duplicating templates, figuring out how the templates are used and then editing them. I chose the simpler route: Give up trying to merge with asdoc's output and instead 'host' the generated content with pages of my own. That is, I use the following site structure:

```
www
  \index.html
  \installation.html
  \gettingstarted.html
  \tutorial1.html
  \asdoc\{auto-generated content here}
```

Each of my helper pages have a navbar that has a link to the asdoc content. Unfortunately, there's no link from the asdoc pages back to the outer ('host') pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the XSLT/CSS used by asdoc using the [`-templates-path`](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/3/html/asdoc_9.html) option. Start by duplicating `%FLEX_HOME%\asdoc\templates` to a custom directory and then make changes to those files.

Comment: I understand how this allows me to change the templates involved, but how does this allow me to add a "Getting Started" sections and pages?

Is there no way to write supporting documentation files?

Comment: There's no built in way. But you could hard code a link to support files in the table of contents by updating the XSLT.